# Calculate monthly and quarterly returns for different Symbols based on their monthly close

Tags: excel-formula, finance

I'm looking for a way to calculate monthly and quarterly returns for different Symbols based on their monthly close.

In column `D` I want to subtract the *close* value from the latest found date in the previous month from the *close* value in the current row provided that the *symbol* equals.

In column `E` I want the same, but for the value of column C of the last date in the month 3 months before the month of the current row.

[image: image of excel]

Comment: How do you want us to guide you if you don't share any data and examples of what you want?

Comment: Sorry my bad, will try to do it again. I want to subtract two cells from column-C based on two conditions. First Symbol (col-A) is same for both the cell and second date (Col-B) is the last day of the month in the table. For Monthly Return(Col-D) the month should be the previous month and for quarterly(Col-E) it should be 3months away. I've attached a new screenshot. Thanks for ur response and time...

Comment: Based on this I was able to provide an answer (and edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

In `D2` you could use:

```
=IFERROR($C2-INDEX($C$2:$C$21,
                MATCH(
                   MAXIFS($B$2:$B$21,
                      $A$2:$A$21,$A2,
                      $B$2:$B$21,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2)-1,1),0), 
                      $B$2:$B$21,">="&DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2)-1,1)),
                   $B$2:$B$21,0)),
         "")
```

Where `MAXIFS` calculates the max date found in the previous month;

`MATCH` returns the *n*th instance where the date matches the calculated max value, which is used in the `INDEX` function which indexes the values in column C.

Finally the value in column C minus the calculated value is the outcome.

If no value is present for the previous month it throws an error, which is covered with `IFERROR` that then returns a blank.

For `D2` you could use a variant of this, replacing both the `MONTH($B2)-1`'s with `MONTH($B2)-3` for looking back 3 months (as explained in your comment).
If you ment actual quarters then change it to look for the max value for the last month in the previous quarter.

[image]

Or if you have Office 365 you can use `LET`:

```
=LET(d,DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2)-1,1),

IFERROR(C2-INDEX($C$2:$C$21,
              XMATCH(                                                          
                 MAXIFS($B$2:$B$21,                    
                   $A$2:$A$21,$A2,                       
                   $B$2:$B$21,"<="&EOMONTH(d,0),                
                   $B$2:$B$21,">="&d),
                 $B$2:$B$21)),
        ""))
```

Comment: Thanks for response.... but I'm looking for monthly returns only so intermediate date should be blank for eg. D4,D6,D8 and D10. similarly for quarterly Returns there will be one value for a quarter.

Comment: Then use: `=LET(d,DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2)-1,1),IF($B2=INDEX($B$2:$B$21,XMATCH(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$21,$A$2:$A$21,$A2,$B$2:$B$21,"<="&EOMONTH($B2,0),$B$2:$B$21,">="&$B2),$B$2:$B$21)),IFERROR($C2-INDEX($C$2:$C$21,XMATCH(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$21,$A$2:$A$21,$A2,$B$2:$B$21,"<="&EOMONTH(d,0),$B$2:$B$21,">="&d),$B$2:$B$21)),""),""))`

Comment: No problem. If it answered the question you can mark it solved and/or vote for the answer.